# how can I get the id of the last inserted event

Tags: android, sqlite, xamarin, xamarin.android, sqlite-net

First of all I am using SQLite-Net-Pcl on Xamarin.Android

My question is this, I need to create an event that is recursive,
and I need to connect all those recursive events (in case of someone edditing them or delleting them).
And I need to use the original Event's Id to connect it to the others

```
-> creates new recursive event  
-> gets the id of inserted event  
-> uses that id to connect all recursive events together on a "NumDocConnection"
```

My Id is auto-incremented, and is the primary key.

So, how can I get the id of the last inserted event? or is this even a good way do to deal with the situation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> how can I get the id of the last inserted event?

The `int`-based primary/auto-inc value is obtained via the object that you inserted (the object instance is updated during the `Insert` with the new value).

```
var newRecord = new Record { SomeString = "StackOverflow" };
var numofRecordsInserted = conn.Insert(newRecord);
Console.WriteLine($"Newly inserted id = {newRecord.Key}");
```

> is this even a good way do to deal with the situation

That depends upon your application. A pri-key/auto-inc field does prevent the reuse of the generated IDs, that is until the database is reset (via deletion/re-creation or a reset via the the `sqlite_sequence` table).

Should you use it as a "foreign" key, lots of `opinions` here, some yes, some no.... Personally if you never use it externally to your app (i.e. it is not transmitted/sync'd via a remote API) it works well/fast as a foreign key if you understand how SQLite creates it and when it can/could be reset, see the linked docs.

> If the AUTOINCREMENT keyword appears after INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, that changes the automatic ROWID assignment algorithm to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs over the lifetime of the database. In other words, the purpose of AUTOINCREMENT is to prevent the reuse of ROWIDs from previously deleted rows.

re: https://sqlite.org/autoinc.html

Comment: Thank you for your time, and thanl you again for your answer, I use the Auto Incremented Id only localy, I have another field that serves as a key for web services I use.

I ended up inserting the first event, getting the last inserted event into the table, and then using the Id that was given as that "NumDocConnection"